# Index of vector field

Tags: differential-topology, vector-fields

Let $F \in C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ and $G \in C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{m}, \mathbb{R}^{m}\right)$ be vector fields with
precisely one singularity at the origin. Let $i(F,0)$ be the index of $F$ at $0$ (the index of $F$ at $0$ is the degree of $\phi$, $\phi: S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$, where $\phi(x)=F(x)/||F(x)||$). Similar for $i(G,0)$ and $i(F\times G,0)$. I want to prove

> $$i(F\times G,0)=i(F,0)i(G,0)$$

I want to prove it by definition, but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: And how are you defining/computing degree? Let's see what you've tried.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin deg of $\phi$ is the number satisfying $\int_{S^{n-1}} \phi^{*}(\omega)=\mathrm{deg \phi} \int_{S^{n-1}} \omega$, for a n-1 form $\omega$ on $S^{n-1}$. Since $S^{n-1}\times S^{m-1}$ is not a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, I do not know how to use this to compute the degree of $F\times G$.

Comment: Aha. The problem is that $S^{n-1}\times S^{m-1}$ maps in an obvious way to $S^{n+m-1}$, but obviously this not an equidimensional mapping. Although you can use volume forms on $S^{m-1}$ and $S^{n-1}$ to define one on their product, this won't help. I think you need a different approach to do this exercise. Assuming you have nondegenerate zeroes (where the index is $\pm 1$), you can do this instead by relating the index to the sign of the Jacobians of $F$, $G$, and $F\times G$.

Comment: Yeah, actually, I have proved that if the zeros are nondegenerated, then the equality holds. However, I do not think we could use this way to prove more general case.

Comment: You can prove that (without the product map) a vector field with a degenerate zero can be perturbed to one with only nondegenerate zeroes, and the sum of the local degrees is the same as the original. That will follow from Stokes's Theorem if you're clever.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about how to perturb the vector field? I think if I know it, I could finish the proof.

Comment: Say $F$ is a vector field on $\Bbb R^m$ and $0$ is an isolated zero on $\|x\|\le 2$. If you know Sard's Theorem, you can choose a vector $a\in\Bbb R^k$ that is a regular value of $F$ and smaller than $\|F(x)\|$ for $1/4\le \|x\|\le 1$. Now choose a bump function $\rho$  with $\rho(x)=1$ for $\|x\|\le 1/2$ and $\rho(x)=0$ for $\|x\|\ge 1$. Let $G=F-\rho a$.

Comment: Oh, I know how to do it now! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. You should post a complete solution if you feel like it. I'll be glad to upvote you if it's right. :)

Comment: I have posted a complete solution. Could you see if it is right? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Step $1$: We want to find a vector field $\widetilde{F}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with only non-degenerate singularities such that $\mathrm{Ind}(F)=\mathrm{Ind}(\widetilde{F}).$ (Here $\mathrm{Ind}(F)$ is just $i(F,0)$). For this we just need to construct a vector field which agree with $F$ outside a compact set, since the index of $F$ and $\widetilde{F}$ only depends on the restriction of them to $\partial B_{R}(0)$ for $R$ sufficiently large.
Let $\beta\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with $\beta(x)\equiv1$ for $||x||\le1$ and $\beta(x)\equiv0$ for $||x||\ge2$. Let $$c=\mathrm{inf}_{1\le||x||\le2} ||F(x)||$$which is positive since $F$ is onle zero at $x=0$. Let $w\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $||w||<c$ be a regular value of $F: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ (by Sard's theorem, regular values are dense in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, so we could find this $w$). Define
$$\widetilde{F}(x):=F(x)-\beta(x)w$$
Then $\widetilde{F}(x)=F(x)$,  if $ ||x||\ge 2. $ $\widetilde{F}(x)\ge c-||w||>0$, if $1\le||x||\le 2$. $\widetilde{F}(x)=F(x)-w$, if $||x||\le 1$.
So all zeros of $\widetilde{F}$ are in $\mathrm{int}(D^{n})$ and  $\widetilde{F}^{-1}(0)=\mathrm{int}(D^{n})\cap F^{-1}(w)$. Since $D\widetilde{F}(p)=DF(p)$ and $w$ is a regular value of $F$, $D\widetilde{F}(p)$ is invertible whenever $p\in\mathrm{int}(D^{n})\cap F^{-1}(w).$ So then zeros of $\widetilde{F}$ are all non-degenerated and isolated, in particular, they are finite.

Step 2: We construct $\widetilde{G} $ similarly. Then $(p,q)$ is a singularity of $\widetilde{F}\times\widetilde{G}$ if and only if $(\widetilde{F}(p),\widetilde{G}(q))=0$ if and only if $p$ is a singularity of $\widetilde{F}$ and $q$ is a singularity of $\widetilde{G}$. Since $D(\widetilde{F}\times\widetilde{G})(p,q)=\left(\begin{array}{ll}{D\widetilde{F}(p)} & {0} \\ {0} & {D\widetilde{G}(q)}\end{array}\right)$, $\mathrm{det}D(\widetilde{F}\times\widetilde{G})(p,q)=\mathrm{det}D\widetilde{F}(p)\mathrm{det}D\widetilde{G}(q)$. Hence (p,q) is a non-degenerate singularity of $\widetilde{F}\times\widetilde{G}$ if and only if $p$ is a non-degenerate singularity of $\widetilde{F}$, $q$ is a non-degenerate singularity of $\widetilde{G}$. In this case, $i(\widetilde{F}\times\widetilde{G})(p,q)$=$\mathrm{sign}(\mathrm{det}D(\widetilde{F}\times\widetilde{G})(p,q))=\mathrm{sign}(\mathrm{det}D\widetilde{F}(p))\mathrm{sign}(\mathrm{det}D\widetilde{G}(q))=i(\widetilde{F},p)i(\widetilde{G},q)$.

Step 3: It is clear that $\mathrm{Ind}(\widetilde{F}\times\widetilde{G})=i(F\times G,0)$. So by step 1 and 2, we have $i(F,0)i(G,0)=\mathrm{Ind}(\widetilde{F})\mathrm{Ind}(\widetilde{G})=(\sum_{p}i(\widetilde{F},p))(\sum_{q}i(\widetilde{G},q))=\sum_{p,q}i(\widetilde{F},p))(\sum_{q}i(\widetilde{G},q))=\sum_{p,q}i(\widetilde{F}\times\widetilde{G},(p,q))=\mathrm{Ind}(\widetilde{F}\times\widetilde{G})=i(F\times G,0)$

Comment: You want $\text{Ind}(\tilde F) = \sum i(\tilde F,x_i)$. But you're missing a major point. Why is $i(F,0) = \sum i(\tilde F,x_i)$? You'll need to use Stokes's Theorem with your definition here. Also, in the nondegenerate case, have you related the sign of the jacobian to the integral definition of degree?